# Use variable value as variable name in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In the code below:

```
DbModels.prototype.updateById = function(_collection, id, field, value, callback) {
    this.getCollection(_collection, function(error, sel_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        sel_collection.update({_id: ObjectID.createFromHexString(id)}, {$set: {$[field].value:value}}, function(error, updated) {
          if( error ) callback(error)
          else callback(null, updated);
        });
      }
    });
};
```

I would like to use the value of the variable field as the name of the variable in $set. I tried using the following code $[field].value (as you can see in the code above), which doesn't work. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is simple: Do not create messy code where hacks like dynamic variable names are necessary.

Comment: What exactly is messy about this approach? What I intend to do is pass the attribute that needs to be updated and then (dynamically) update only the changed attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not such syntax in javascript as php `${$var_name}`;

One can use `this[var_name]` or `window[var_name]` (for global vars in browsers), but there's no way to get local variable in current scope except `eval`, which is definitely considered bad.

Consider using a hash (object) for variable "scoping/namespacing".

Comment: With the last part do you mean something like:
var parameters = {};
        parameters[firstVariableName] = field;
        sel_collection.update({_id: ObjectID.createFromHexString(id)}, {$set: {parameters[firstVariableName]:value}},................

Comment: Yes, except one can't write object literals this way. And it could be actually done a bit simpler: `var setParameters = {}; setParameters[parameters[firstVariableName]] = value; sel_collection.update({_id: ObjectID.createFromHexString(id)}, {$set: setParameters}`